# Format time span for CV

Tags: tables, formatting, moderncv, tabu

I would like to add the month to the time span of *moderncv*. I order not to occupy much more space and still having a beautiful solution, I would like to do the following:
Year - Year
Month - Month
where

- there's just one dash vertically centered in between the two dates,
- the month is centered under the year
- the year is stretched to the cell width if necessary
- to occupy little space, there are no margins at all

I already did some experiments, but couldn't get the margins and the stretching right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand* \hintscolumnwidth {0.2\textwidth} % best: 0.175\textwidth

\newcommand \testBb [4]{%
     \begin{tabu} to \hintscolumnwidth {|@{} X[c m] @{--} X[c m] @{}|}
     \hline \linespread{0}#2\newline \tiny #1&\linespread{0}#4 \newline\tiny #3 \\ \hline
     \end{tabu}}

\newcommand \testB [4]{%
     \begin{tabu} to \hintscolumnwidth {|@{} X[c m] @{}|@{} X[c m] @{}|}
     \hline \linespread{0}#2\newline \tiny #1&\linespread{0}#4 \newline\tiny #3  \\\hline
     \end{tabu}}

\newcommand \testA [4]{%
    \begin{tabu} to \hintscolumnwidth {@{}|X[-1,m,c]|@{--}X[-1,m, c]|@{}}  %spread 2cm
        \hline      {#2 } & #4 \\ \tiny #1 & \tiny #3\\ \hline 
    \end{tabu}}

\def \dateA [#1.#2-#3.#4]{ \testA{\monthname[#1]} {#2}  {\monthname[#3]}  {#4} }
\def \dateB [#1.#2-#3.#4]{ \testB{\monthname[#1]} {#2}  {\monthname[#3]}  {#4} }
\def \dateBb [#1.#2-#3.#4]{ \testBb{\monthname[#1]} {#2}  {\monthname[#3]}  {#4} }

\begin{document}%
\ \\
\dateA[09.2008-09.2012]\ \\
\dateB[09.2008-09.2012]\ \\
\dateBb[09.2008-09.2012]\ \\
2008--2012
\end{document}
```

Produces the following result:
[image: Result]

Any suggestions how to make it even more beautiful are welcome.

**Update:**
I took one step back and solved it by just using boxes. My problem with them is that I have to replace \ by \newline if want to use them in the existing tabu cells. This messes up line spacing, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand* \datumsZellenBreite {11mm}
\newcommand* \datumsZifferMonatsAbstand{-0.8mm}
\newcommand \zeitspanneA[4]{%same as B, but uses \newline instead of \\ for linebreak
    {\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#2%
    %\\%
    \newline
    \vspace{-2.8mm}\tiny #1}}}\hspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}{\raisebox{0.4mm}{\color{blue}$\rightarrow$}}\hspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}{\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#4%
    %\\%
    \newline
    \vspace{-2.8mm}\tiny #3}}}
}
\def \zeitA [#1.#2-#3.#4]{ \zeitspanneA{\monthname[#1]} {#2}  {\monthname[#3]}  {#4} }

\newcommand \zeitspanneB[4]{
    {{\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#2\\\vspace{-2.8mm}\tiny #1}}}\hspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}{\raisebox{0.4mm}{\color{blue}$\rightarrow$}}\hspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}{\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#4\\\vspace{-2.8mm}\tiny #3}}}}
}
\def \zeitB [#1.#2-#3.#4]{ \zeitspanneB{\monthname[#1]} {#2}  {\monthname[#3]}  {#4} }

\begin{document}%
A should look like B, so it can be used inside tabu.\\ \ \\
\zeitB[09.2008-09.2012]\ B\\ \\
\zeitA[09.2008-09.2012]\ A\\ \\

\begin{tabu}{XX}
a & \zeitA[09.2008-09.2012] %can't use B here
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Results in
[image: boxExample]

**Update2:**
I'm now pretty close to what I desire. Actually the `\baselineskip=-valA\newline\par\vspace{-valA}` to get the year-month spacing right seems like voodoo to me, but I should sacrifice a goat for finding it. The only thing that's undesired is that **A doesn't start at the same baseline as the digits do**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newcommand* \datumsZellenBreite {10.5mm}
\newcommand* \datumsZifferMonatsAbstand{-2.8mm}
\newcommand \zeitspanne[4]{%same as B, but uses \newline instead of \\ for linebreak
    {\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#2\baselineskip=\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand\newline\par\vspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}\tiny{\strut#1}}}}\hspace{-0.6mm}{\raisebox{0.35mm}{\color{blue}--}}\hspace{-0.2mm}%
    {\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#4\baselineskip=\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand\newline\par\vspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}\tiny{\strut#3}}}}%
}
\def \zeit[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\zeitspanne{\monthname[#1]}{#2}{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tabu}{@{}X[-1]@{}|X@{}}
\hline%
A & \zeit[09.2008-09.2012]
\\\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Datum3]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: `tabu` might not be a good choice for a document that will continue to evolve. The author of the package is revising it and promising that there will **not** be backwards compatibility; see [here](http://tinyurl.com/bscce5t).

Comment: Have you seen [`moderntimeline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline)?

Comment: I thought `tabu` is the newest table package and thus the first choice. I've now taken a look at `moderntimeline`, it looks nice, but it's not what I want.

Comment: I think that after the edit, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Don't the two possibilities I suggested in my answer give you (after changing the en-dash for the colored arrow) the result you are looking for? If not, could you please explain what are they lacking to achieve your layout?

Comment: your suggested answer came pretty close. I just wanted to improve the year-month spacing, reduce the borders, adjust the dash to the middle and use it inside existing tabu cells. I'm probably going to accept your answer as soon as I have the desired result.

Comment: You can use `[t]` for both `\parbox`es, as in `\parbox[t]{\datumsZellenBreite}{...}`. This will lower the dates so the baseline will be the same.

Comment: Yes, that's working, the only drawback is that the hole cell size increases. Another option would be to use `\vspace{-3mm}A`, but this seems a bit hacky. So if someone knows a cleaner solution ... :) Thanks a lot so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? I used [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) instead of `tabu`. The vertical alignment for the `tabularx` was set to `[t]`, and `\firsthline` (from the `array` package) was used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand*\hintscolumnwidth{0.2\textwidth} % best: 0.175\textwidth

\def\dateS[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\testS{\monthname[#1]}{#2}{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}

\newcommand\testS[4]{%
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{tabularx}{\hintscolumnwidth}[t]{|@{}Y@{}c@{}Y@{}|}
\firsthline
#2 &\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{--} & #4 \\[-1ex]
\tiny#1 && \tiny#3 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}}}

\begin{document}%

\dateS[09.2008-12.2012] Some text\par
\dateS[01.1997-09.2012] Some text\par
\dateS[09.2000-09.2012] Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

And using boxes (`minipage`s and `\parbox`es, in this case), one doesn't need any additional package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{--}
\newlength\hintscolumnwidth
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{0.2\textwidth} % best: 0.175\textwidth

\def\dateS[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\testS{\monthname[#1]}{#2}{\monthname[#3]}{#4}}

\newcommand\testS[4]{%
{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}
\parbox[t]{0.5\hintscolumnwidth}{\centering%
\raggedright%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{\dimexpr0.5\hintscolumnwidth-2\mylen\relax}--}%
\centering#2\\ \tiny#1
}%
\parbox[t]{0.5\hintscolumnwidth}{\centering%
#4\\ \tiny#3
}%
\end{minipage}}}}

\begin{document}%

\dateS[09.2008-12.2012] Some text\par
\dateS[01.1997-09.2012] Some text\par
\dateS[09.2000-09.2012] Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**glyj** from #latex suggested another using *tikz*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu,xcolor}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newcommand* \datumsZellenBreite {10.5mm}
\newcommand* \datumsZifferMonatsAbstand{-2.8mm}
\newcommand \zeitspanne[4]{
        {\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#2\baselineskip=\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand\newline\par\vspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}\tiny{\strut#1}}}}\hspace{-0.6mm}{\raisebox{0.35mm}{\color{blue}--}}\hspace{-0.2mm}%
        {\parbox{\datumsZellenBreite}{\centering{#4\baselineskip=\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand\newline\par\vspace{\datumsZifferMonatsAbstand}\tiny{\strut#3}}}}%
}
\def \zeit[#1.#2-#3.#4]{\zeitspanne{\monthname[#1]}{\ #2}{\monthname[#3]}{\ #4}}

\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0cm,0cm) rectangle (\textwidth,1cm);
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (\textwidth,0);
  \coordinate (I) at (0.5,0);
  \coordinate (J) at (0.5,1);
  \coordinate (Zeitpos) at (1,0.5);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (D) at (\textwidth,1);

  \draw  (0,0.6) node {A};
  \draw (A)--(B);
  \draw (C)--(D);
  \draw (Zeitpos) node [right] {\zeit[09.2008-03.2012]};
  \draw (I)--(J);      
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabu}{@{}X[-1]@{}|X@{}}
\hline%
A & \zeit[09.2008-03.2012]
\\\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```